# how can to center overflow columns of bootstrap row?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, styles, row

I want to center every element of a boostrap row that overflows,
for example:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-2"> col-lg-2 </div>
  <div class="col-lg-2"> col-lg-2 </div>
  <div class="col-lg-2"> col-lg-2 </div>
  <div class="col-lg-2"> col-lg-2 </div>
  <div class="col-lg-2"> col-lg-2 </div>
  <div class="col-lg-2"> col-lg-2 </div>
  <div class="col-lg-2"> col-lg-2 </div>
  <div class="col-lg-2"> col-lg-2 </div>
  <div class="col-lg-2"> col-lg-2 </div>
</div>
```

So this row has 6 columns and then overflows in 3 columns.
I want that the last three columns align in the center, like `margin: auto` (see example image). I'd like to use a single style for the row.

Image of what I have now and what I want to achieve:

[image: Image on Imgur]

Comment: Hey, it would be great if you can pay attention to wording and formatting of your question. It would help the community to answer your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add the class **justify-content-center** to your, row as described in the [grid system documentation of BS4](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/), in section [#Horizontal alignment](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/#horizontal-alignment).

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="row justify-content-center">
  <div class="col-lg-2"> col-lg-2 </div>
  <div class="col-lg-2"> col-lg-2 </div>
  <div class="col-lg-2"> col-lg-2 </div>
  <div class="col-lg-2"> col-lg-2 </div>
  <div class="col-lg-2"> col-lg-2 </div>
  <div class="col-lg-2"> col-lg-2 </div>
  <div class="col-lg-2"> col-lg-2 </div>
  <div class="col-lg-2"> col-lg-2 </div>
  <div class="col-lg-2"> col-lg-2 </div>
</div>
```